# Scala - cannot infer type from Generic

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and cannot get this code work right, any help will be appreciated! Here's what I have

```
sealed trait List[+A] {
  def foldRight[B](f: (B, A) => B, acc: B): B = {
    def go(acc: B, list: List[A]): B = list match {
      case Nil => acc
      case Cons(x, xs) => go(f(acc, x), xs)
    }
    go(acc, this)
  }
}

case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](x: A, xs: List[A]) extends List[A]

val list: List[Int] = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, Nil))))
val acc: Int = 0

// this one works
println(list.foldRight((x: Int, y: Int) => x + y, acc))

// this one says cannot resolve symbol +
println(list.foldRight((x, y) => x + y, acc))
```

I don't understand why it cannot infer the types, because list is List[Int] (A) and the second arg to foldRight is Int (B). Any thoughts?

Comment: The gist of the duped answer is: use currying to get the compiler to infer the right type.

Answer (score 0):

**Scala Compiler needs help**

Here Scala compiler is unable to infer the types for you because `+` can be string concatenation operator or numeric addition operator. To get rid of this confusion you have to provide at least the output type `B` as `Int`.

You need to tell at least what type `B` belongs to help compiler know weather `+` is string concatenation or numeric addition.

Tell compiler what is `B` (result type) or tell compiler what is `x` and `y`

`list.foldRight[Int]( (x, y) => x + y , acc )`

Below code works

```
println(list.foldRight[Int]( (x, y) => x + y , acc ) )
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed trait List[+A] {
  def foldRight[B](f: (B, A) => B, acc: B): B = {
    def go(acc: B, list: List[A]): B = list match {
      case Nil => acc
      case Cons(x, xs) => go(f(acc, x), xs)
    }
    go(acc, this)
  }
}

case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](x: A, xs: List[A]) extends List[A]

val list: List[Int] = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, Nil))))
val acc: Int = 0

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait List
defined object Nil
defined class Cons
list: List[Int] = Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Cons(4,Nil))))
acc: Int = 0

scala> println(list.foldRight[Int]( (x, y) => x + y , acc ) )
10
```

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic way to use lambda functions in scala without explicitly specifying types is `case`:

```
println(list.foldRight({ case (x, y) => x + y }, acc))
```

Comment: This will not work